# scip installation on Linux Server - Bliss failing

Tags: scip

So I am about install the scipoptsuite 7.0.3 on a Linux Server, but get this weird error message.

```
/opt/scipoptsuite-7.0.3/scip/src/symmetry/compute_symmetry_bliss.cpp: In function ‘SCIP_RETCODE SYMcomputeSymmetryGenerators(SCIP*, int, SYM_MATRIXDATA*, int*, int*, int***, double*)’:
/opt/scipoptsuite-7.0.3/scip/src/symmetry/compute_symmetry_bliss.cpp:377:32: error: cannot convert ‘void(void*, unsigned int, const unsigned int*)’ to ‘const std::function<void(unsigned int, const unsigned int*)>&’
  377 |    G.find_automorphisms(stats, blisshook, (void*) &data);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                |
      |                                void(void*, unsigned int, const unsigned int*)
In file included from /usr/local/include/bliss/graph.hh:22,
                 from /opt/scipoptsuite-7.0.3/scip/src/symmetry/compute_symmetry_bliss.cpp:28:
/usr/local/include/bliss/abstractgraph.hh:175:95: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void bliss::AbstractGraph::find_automorphisms(bliss::Stats&, const std::function<void(unsigned int, const unsigned int*)>&, const std::function<bool()>&)’
  175 |                           const std::function<void(unsigned int n, const unsigned int* aut)>& report = nullptr,
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scip/src/CMakeFiles/libscip.dir/build.make:4587: scip/src/CMakeFiles/libscip.dir/symmetry/compute_symmetry_bliss.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2300: scip/src/CMakeFiles/libscip.dir/all] Error 2
```

Bliss version installed is 0.77

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you are not using the most recent version of SCIP? I think there is a version mismatch between your bliss version and the somewhat outdated version of SCIP you are trying to install. If you switch to SCIP 8.0.1 or newer the problem should disappear (and in upcoming release bliss will even be automatically be shipped with SCIP)

Comment: Yeah there is in fact a reason why I need an older version of scip. But I just turned BLISS of and was then able to compile this version of scip.

Comment: If you think symmetry handling is important for your project, I think you need bliss version 0.73 for SCIP 7.0.1, I hope this version http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/ will work.